# Delete metadata in multiple files

Tags: html, replace, metadata

How do i use Find and Replace in Files in Notepad++ to delete the following lines from multiple files?

```
<meta name="perc_linkback" id="perc_linkback" content="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="xxxxxxxxxxx.html"/>
```

Where xxxxxxxxxxx is a string of different characters that varies in length.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question sounds like it's more about how to use some particular software (Notepad++) rather than how to program your own software. As such it's probably more suited to our sister site: SuperUser. You can get there by clicking the Stack Exchange link at the top left of your screen and searching for SuperUser

Comment: This question on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/937217/delete-metadata-in-multiple-files